# JQuery Weather Tomorrow

Tags: jquery, weather

so I'm trying to add integrate a Weather app in my site, this works fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/fleeting/a4hbL/light/

The only problem I am having is getting it to output the Weather **tomorrow** rather than currently. 
Any ideas? I don't need Geolocation or anything like that (just in case you were wondering), this is a local project. But I do need it to do as I have specified above.

It's this that I need to change:

```
weather.currently
```

But I can't seem to figure out how I can add an option to make it display the weather tomorrow...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the docs, you'd see that there are parameters for tomorrow's date, such as `tomorrow.high`, `tomorrow.highAlt`, `tomorrow.forecast`...

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/a4hbL/2064/

And please read the docs before posting a question here.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a bit of a rush... Thanks for replying though.

Comment: No problem, but you know, the time it took to write the question and the time it would take to read the docs... :)  Btw. just curious, why did you pick the other answer since I gave you all the details and the working version?

Comment: You could have it lol... Anyway, would something like this work?  `if(tomorrow.highAlt > 16) {
 echo "<h1>hello</h1>";
}` I get an error for "unexpected string" in the console.

Comment: It could be that the api returns a string instead of an integer, so you could do `if(parseInt(tomorrow.highAlt, 10) > 16) { echo "<h1>hello</h1>"; }` and get really creative with all the data you get.

Comment: Same error, I spaced the code out and the Console highlighted this: `echo "<h1>hello</h1>";` Any ideas?

Comment: Wait, wait, wait... is that PHP now? (because of echo) You can use alert, console.log, document.write, but not echo as it doesn't exist in JS :) Sorry, completely missed it

Comment: Try this: `if(parseInt(tomorrow.highAlt, 10) > 16) { alert("hello"); }`

Comment: That worked! But I now I've got a reference error for "tomorrow is undefined"... (I have that code under <script></script> tags in the html) Also, would this work: `$("body").html("<h2>hello</h2>");`? Sorry for the bother, I'll have to review my JQuery...

Comment: Yeah, don't forget the weather... so it's `weather.tomorrow.highAlt`... Yes, the other part will work, it will erase everything you have on the page and put h2 element with 'hello' inside it.

Comment: I definitely don't want that, if I created a <div id="hi"> and did something like `$("hi").body("<p>A is equal to B</p>");` would that work? I basically want it to output on the page and not delete anything else.

Comment: That won't work, read about jQuery selectors and functions. You need something like this: `$("#hi").html("<p>A is equal to B</p>");`